# Get value from JavaScript to Livewire Component

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-livewire

Could you tell me if it is possible to get the value of a JavaScript field and pass it to a Laravel Livewire property:

First I load in an input with JavaScript the following value:

```
document.getElementById('lat-span').value = (place.geometry['location'].lat());
```

This loads the input with the value, now I tried to retrieve that value with wire: model and it appears null, I understand that it is not done the way I had in mind:

```
<input  wire:model="latitud" value="lat-span" id="lat-span" />
```

How can I directly pass this JavaScript value to Livewire property?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<script>
// ....
Livewire.emit('getLatitudeForInput', place.geometry['location'].lat());
</script>
```

In component:

```
public $latitud;
protected $listeners = [
     'getLatitudeForInput'
];
//
public function getLatitudeForInput($value)
{
    if(!is_null($value))
        $this->latitud = $value;
}
```

In Blade just:

```
<input  wire:model="latitud" id="lat-span" />
```

Comment: This works perfect, although I have a doubt about its functionality, for example I need to also add the length and other properties, here it seems that it is a unique method or could I pass more values?

Comment: I don't do that before, but I think that you can build an object or an array in JQuery and then it can be emitted to the component by this way

Comment: Hello @Prospero I ask you a question, it worked well in a test project but in a production project I get the following error: Livewire.emit is not a function. I would be very grateful if you can give me a suggestion

Answer (score 4):

```
<script>
@this.set('latitud', place.geometry['location'].lat());
</script>
```

Try this inside script tag

Comment: Something like that would be perfect, but it doesn't work for me. Basically this should set the property with the value?